# If $A$ is closed linear operator then $\lambda I-A$ is one-to-one.

Tags: functional-analysis

If $A:D(A)\subset X \longrightarrow X$ is a closed linear operator, with dense domain in $X$, such that 
$$||\lambda x - Ax||>0, \:\forall \: x\in D(A).$$

Then $\lambda I -A$ is one-to-one. Is this statement true? If so, why?

Comment: To begin with, the condition $\|\lambda x- Ax\|>0$ cannot hold for $x=0$.

Comment: And if it's for all $x \neq 0$ ?

Comment: $\forall x \in X$ including $x$ not in the domain of $A$?

Comment: In the domain of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple linear algebra fact. A linear operator is one-to-one if and only if it has trivial kernel. The condition you wrote is a reformulation of this fact.

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Comment: @guilherme: You are welcome.